# What does here "was revered to commit" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> His will to do good was used against him and was revered to commit the worst acts possible. [<sub>Source</sub>](https://screenrant.com/best-sith-lords-from-the-old-republic/)

How can it be interpreted in easier words?

Comment: I can't begin to imagine how this came to be written. I think it's unlikely we're dealing with a (very rare) ***slang*** usage here, but I can't easily think what kind of ***typo*** could have led to it. The only short sequence of words I can think of that would even make sense here would be something like *...and **he was made** to commit unspeakable acts*. Syntactically speaking, the text as given seems to be talking about ***something else*** that was done to / with "his will to do good", but semantically speaking that seems bogglingly unlikely. I'd say it's just "badly written".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica That’s not the only weird bit of writing - a quick scan revealed *Their curiosity and passion got would be their downfall as they were brainwashed by the Sith.* Apparently there is no editor checking the writing quality.

Comment: I have to say that a typo does explicate the passage. "Reversed" instead of "revered" makes sense of the passage though I cannot say I am enamored of the style. "His will to do good was used against him in terrible acts." (I know: comments about style are outside scope.)

Comment: @JeffMorrow Skimming the rest of the article leads me to believe the writer is just not very competent with English.

Comment: @ColleenV I was not disagreeing with you about the competence of the writer. I was just pointing out that the sentence is intelligible assuming a typo of the kind that spellcheckers do not catch.

Comment: @JeffMorrow My point was given the other errors in the text, it’s unlikely to be a typo, for example *the Sith looked unearth the dormant potential within each apprentice.* Honestly I think it’s more likely this was written by a Markov chain computer algorithm than a person. There are lots of places that we could add or change words to sort of fix it, but there’s something very off about the writing.

Comment: @ColleenV I cannot argue for the competence of the writer, but, in this specific instance, "reversed" for "revered" makes complete sense in context. It is not some strained reading. But, as I said, I don't want to argue so I shall just drop out of this thread.

Comment: @ColleenV Where can I find a discussion on this site about "a Markov chain computer algorithm" and how to detect it. I can usually detect L1-L2 confusion, but this is a new one on me. We now need to deal with errors in  usage  generated by machines?

Comment: @Cascabel This article explains it a bit https://everipedia.org/wiki/lang_en/Markov_chain#Markov_text_generators Not long ago, it was trendy to use Markov chain based algorithms to generate realistic seeming text by training them with particular types of documents. There’s something weird about the mistakes in this article that make me think automated translation or something similar. I don’t think it’s actually Markov text generation, because it would probably have less actual information and more semantic filler.

Comment: @ColleenV Thanks..I will certainly look into this 'weird' stuff...fascinating.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's based on faulty English. Nothing to learn from it here

Answer (score 0):

Well, the key word to understand here is *commit*. Here are some relevant [dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commit) definitions

> 1. to do something illegal or something that is considered wrong:
> 2. to actively put information in your memory or write it down:

As regards the word *revere*, it is [defined](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/revere) as

> to very much respect and admire someone or something

Therefore, the phrase "*[to be] revered to commit*" seems to indicate that the subject was greatly admired, which resulted in his *committing* something; either some action, or committing something into memory.

Comment: If the admiration of others was the reason a person chose to act, then you could say that *(the people’s) reverence compelled (the person) to commit* the act. If the action was the cause for admiration you could say *(the person) was revered for committing* the act. It doesn’t make sense to say that they were *revered to commit* the action.